# ffmpeg как сделать рандомный шум

Tags: ffmpeg

Я накладываю шум при помощи команды:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i final.mp4 -vf noise=alls=1:allf=t nG_1.mp4
```

Но мне надо сделать так, чтобы шум был всегда рандомный.

Я пробовал использовать параметр **seed** и указывать рандомное число.
Но при использование seed всегда выходит ошибка.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i final.mp4 -vf noise=alls=1:allf=t:seed=51 nG_1.mp4
```

Error applying option 'seed' to filter 'noise': Option not found
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[aac @ 0000025033a821c0] Qavg: 151.531
[aac @ 0000025033a821c0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!

по разному использовал seed, но всегда выходит ошибка.

Comment: Ну если верить [документации](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#noise), то не `seed`, а `all_seed` например?

Answer (score 0):

а если так попробовать:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i final.mp4 -vf noise=alls=1:allf=t:seed=random nG_1.mp4
```